# MS Bot Framework's Call button not working on Facebook Messenger

Tags: botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I implemented a Herocard with a `CardAction.call` button as shown in the snippet below but it only works (displays) on the Website channel. It doesn't show at all on Messenger (see screenshots attached).

```
var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
        .title(places[session.dialogData.mealType][choicePlaceId][0])
        .subtitle(places[session.dialogData.mealType][choicePlaceId][1])
        .text(places[session.dialogData.mealType][choicePlaceId][3])
        .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.call(session, '+210123456789', 'Call')
        ]);
    var msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(card);
    session.send(msg);
```

**Web Chat Channel:**

[image: Screenshot]

---

---

**FB Messenger Channel:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The Call action is only available on Skype, not on Facebook Messenger

Answer (score 1):

Use the "openUrl" type and the value in "tel:xxxxxxxxx" format. It works for me.

Example:

```
var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
    .title(places[session.dialogData.mealType][choicePlaceId][0])
    .subtitle(places[session.dialogData.mealType][choicePlaceId][1])
    .text(places[session.dialogData.mealType][choicePlaceId][3])
    .buttons([
        builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'tel:+210123456789', 'Call')
    ]);
```